# Isolate shared stubs between components

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I'm defining stubs of services in a separated .ts file which is used in several components (which avoid me to define the same stub in every component). 
The problem is that it leads to random unit tests, because when a component modify an attribute of a stub, the next component which will use this stub will be affected.

I'm defining my serviceStub using the spread operator to use a new reference everytime, but seems to be not enough.

```
export const myserviceStub = {
  ...{
    function1() {},
    propertyA: new BehaviorSubject(false),
  }
};
```

and use this stub in a beforeEach with test bed with :

```
providers: [
        { provide: myService, useValue: myserviceStub },
```

I'm expecting myServiceStub to be as defined in my file, and not depending of the order of units tests.

Answer (score 1):

You should treat your objects as immutable, using the spread operator in the definition of a constant in a separate file won't prevent your from changing the inner references of the object. Every time you import this const, it will always use the same reference.

To get a different reference, you can use the `useFactory` on the provider and declare a stub factory in your shared stub file:

```
export const myserviceStub = {
  function1() {},
  propertyA: new BehaviorSubject(false)
};

export function myServiceStubFactory() {
  return { ...myserviceStub };
}
```

You can then provide it like this:

```
providers: [
   { provide: myService, useFactory: myserviceStub }
]
```

However, this will still share the BehaviorSubject defined on `propertyA`, to change this you have to update your factory:

```
export function myServiceStubFactory() {
  return { 
    ...myserviceStub,
    propertyA: new BehaviorSubject(false)
  };
}
```

So, all in all, it might be better to just use a factory all together, and no fixed object, and define your entire object inside the factory return method

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer.
I finally find a way by using Object.create() in order to have a new reference.